# GAE handlers in app.yaml, does having the same script value multiple time can cause performance issue?

Tags: google-app-engine

From my understanding, I configured my app.yaml the following :

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/?
  script: wsgi.application
  login: admin

- url: .*
  script: wsgi.application
```

The idea behind it is that the full application is managed by the same codebase (queues & web service).
Since I don't want to have my users access the queue url (/_ah/queue/{queue_name}), I added a `login: admin` restriction, and for the rest, everyone can access it.

But I'm wondering if adding the same `script: wsgi.application` is a good way or I'm making something wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem using the same `script:` value for multiple handlers, in fact you can see that even in the example from the [`Script handlers` section of the `Configuring with app.yaml` doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Script_handlers):

> ```
> handlers:
> # The root URL (/) is handled by the WSGI application named "app" in home.py.
> # No other URLs match this pattern.
> - url: /
>   script: home.app
>
> # The URL /index.html is also handled by the home.py script.
> - url: /index\.html
>   script: home.app
> ```

The `script:` statement is simply mapping a handler script/app to the respective url pattern, nothing bad with multiple patterns having the same handler.